# How to Find $y$ Coordinate of a Point on a Line When its $x$ Coordinate is Given?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the $y$ coordinate of a point on a line for given $x$ coordinate values. Please see the following link.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJxYW.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is really not clear! :) I don't understand it!

Comment: I have a curve on a graph. I know its X axis point. How to find its Y axis point ?

Comment: You have some **serious** terminology issues! Please try to improve your English! :) I will write an answer for you but before asking any questions be sure that it is properly stated! :)

Comment: see the above picture....

Comment: Take a look at the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a line, at the first step, you should try to write down its equation. It can be done when you know **the slope** of the line and **the coordinates of one point on that line**. Also, if you know the coordinate of **two** points on the line then you can write its equation down.

**Case 1**. suppose the slope is $m$ and the point $(x_1,y_1)$ lies on the line. Hence the equation of your line will be

$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)\tag{1}$$

**Case 2**. suppose you know the coordinates of two points, namely $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, lying on that line. First you compute the slope and then you write down the equation of the line. Hence, the equation of the line can be written as

$$y - {y_1} = {{{y_2} - {y_1}} \over {{x_2} - {x_1}}}\left( {x - {x_1}} \right)\tag{2}$$
or
$$y - {y_2} = {{{y_2} - {y_1}} \over {{x_2} - {x_1}}}\left( {x - {x_2}} \right)\tag{3}$$

compare $(2)$ or $(3)$ with $(1)$. Now, for any given value $x=x_0$ you can use one of these equations to compute the $y$ coordinate for that given $x$.